# Python csv Module Error: index out of range

Tags: python, csv, index-error

I have a CSV file and I want to extract columns from it, but only from some of the rows. It looks like this:

```
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, gene_name, RERG

gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186

gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186

gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186

gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
```

Essentially I want the 2nd and 6th column, but only from the rows which have "gene_name" in the 5th column. So I want to extract:

```
ENSDARG00000104632, RERG
```

(It goes on from there with many thousands of rows)

This is what I wrote:

```
import csv


with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as infh:
        reader = csv.reader(infh)
        for row in reader:
                if row[4] == 'gene_name':
                        print row[1, 5]
```

However, it gives me this error:

> File "./gene_name_grabber.sh", line 10, in 
>       `if row[4] == 'gene_name':` IndexError: list index out of range

I understand that this error means I've asked it to look at an index number greater than the number of indexes in the rows...but there are clearly more than 4 indexes in each row. Help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that all your lines have the same number of columns? Can you add a print statement right before the `if` condition, so that we can see the line that gives this error?

Comment: I changed it to this:

    import csv


with open('zebrafish_gtf_IDs_and_names.csv', 'rb') as infh:
        reader = csv.reader(infh)
        for row in reader:
                print row
                if row[4] == 'gene_name':
                        print row[1, 5]

but it still gives me this error: File "./gene_name_grabber.sh", line 11, in  if row[4] == 'gene_name': IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Which line does it print last?

Comment: It prints no lines

Comment: Just the error and nothing else

Comment: Wait. It prints this: ['', ' ']

and then the error message. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Looks like your first few lines may not have 5 columns :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there are some rows that do not contain enough columns. Try this:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        try:
            if 'gene_name' in row[4]:
                print('%s, %s' % (row[1].strip(), row[5].strip()))
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

...output:

> ENSDARG00000104632, RERG

Comment: This did work, although it surrounded the elements in each column with ('

So that they look like this: ('ENSDARG00000104632', 'RERG')

Is there a way to make it so the output is simply: ENSDARG00000104632, RERG    ?

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you very much this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the 2nd and 6th column, but only from the rows which have "gene_name" in the 5th column.

I love python. But this is most naturally expressed as

```
awk '$5 ~ /gene_name/ {print $2, $6}'
```

Let's move back to python. This isn't what you wanted to write:

```
                    print row[1, 5]
```

Phrase it as `print(row[1], row[5])` instead.

Some of your lines have only a small number of columns. So you'll want to wrap dereferences of e.g. `row[4]` or `row[5]` in an `if` statement that verifies it's a long enough line:

```
    if len(row) > 5:
        ...
```

Comment: I tried using the awk command, but it didn't seem to do anything at all. I wrote it like this: 

cat filename.csv | awk '$5 ~ /^gene_name$/ {print $2, $6}' > newfile.csv

Is this not correct?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have anchored it. I will revise the answer to delete ^ and $ as they're not needed in an awk context.

Answer (score 0):

As Antimony noted, it sounds as though your data has occasional missing values in it, which csv cannot easily handle out-of-the-box. I'd suggest using a library like pandas which has a `read_csv` function, and can handle missing values. Using this data as an example:

```
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, gene_name, RERG
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id,
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, , transcript_id,
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
```

it could be read as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Use the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns - i.e.column indices 1, 4 and 5 respectively
# And, we set the 'not available' data - i.e. `na_values` as 'N/A'.
data = pd.read_csv('test.dat', na_values='N/A', header=None, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[1,4,5])

# now select only the rows without 'gene_version':
d = data.loc[data[4] != 'gene_name']

# and, now we only select columns with index 1 and 5:
selected_data = d[[1, 5]]
```

Yielding:

```
                    1                   5
0  ENSDARG00000104632                RERG
1  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
2  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
3  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
4  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
5  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
6  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
7  ENSDARG00000104632                 NaN
8  ENSDARG00000104632                 NaN
9  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
```

As desired.

However, if there is missing data - like in this example - all you'll have to do is remove those rows like:

```
selected_data.dropna()
```

Which outputs:

```
                    1                   5
1  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
2  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
3  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
4  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
5  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
6  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
9  ENSDARG00000104632  ENSDART00000166186
```

(However, this may not be what you want.)

REFERENCE

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: You said `usecols=[1, 5]` but I think you need `usecols=[1, 4, 5]`. That way you preserve enough information to mask out any rows where element 4 is not "gene_name".

Comment: @JH Ah! Good catch!! Thanks! Edited.